# Can the water stains in this hardwood floor be sanded out?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing, refinishing

Do you think sanding will be able to take out these water marks, or do the boards need to be replaced? The water damage is old (prior to the previous owner, so at least 12 years) and the floor is possibly heart pine (definitely soft). I plan to sand & refinish the whole 2nd floor.

Thanks!

[image: FloorFromRight]

[image: FloorFromLeft]

[image: FloorWorst]

Comment: What was the source of the previous damage? Did they lay carpet over the hardwood? Does the house have humidity issues? Is the floor warped/uneven in addition to being water-damaged?

Comment: What is the age of the house and of the floor?

Comment: Age of house: built 1910. Source of damage: No idea the because it is from 2 owners ago (I just moved in) but there is a skylight above that hallway that seems like the likely culprit. The wood is not at all warped or uneven. The basement has humidity and I run a dehumidifier there, but this is the 2nd floor and I haven't noticed that extend upward.   @isherwood I'm looking for feedback on how to go about this.. if you don't think you can be helpful not replying is better.

Comment: I think I see a cut off nail in one of those stains. Are there cut off nails in some of the stains? Could be "iron staining."

Comment: After the floor is sanded down to bare wood, just before the last cut is made, treat the spots with oxalic acid. It may remove all of the stains, or get it so it will look acceptable. The rest will sand out. Use it only on the gray areas.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would get a chisel and knock out just one flooring strip. Preferably one of the most damaged strips, and preferably from the edge like under the quarter round. Pull it up and actually test sanding it with an orbital or even just by hand. See how much material you need to remove and consider the final thickness of the flooring - if it's already had three or four rounds of sanding and you're down to the tongues and grooves, it's time for a new floor! If you decide to move forward with a sanding, you can just apply a poly construction adhesive and lay it back down (it will be annoying to remove when it finally is time for a new floor, so others may disagree) or you can face nail it back and try to use a wax filler over the nailheads.

Comment: That's helpful thank you!